# I want to delete a row of information from jtable right after i save all the info can i do so?

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, jtable, text-files

I want to delete a row of information from jtable right after i save all the info can i do so?

```
private void buyButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
                 try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("BuyItem.txt", true);
            writer.write(accNameTextField.getText() + "//" + jTextField1.getText() + "//" + jTextField3.getText() + "//" + jTextField4.getText() + "//" + jTextField5.getText() + "//"+ "\n");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Iteam Bought");
            writer.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }     


private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    int index = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
    TableModel model = jTable1.getModel();
    String Name = model.getValueAt(index, 0).toString();
    String Price = model.getValueAt(index, 1).toString();
    String Category = model.getValueAt(index, 2).toString();
    String Method_of_Delivery = model.getValueAt(index, 3).toString();
    String Condition = model.getValueAt(index, 4).toString();

     jtRowData.setVisible(true);
    jtRowData.pack();
    jtRowData.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    jtRowData.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    jtRowData.jTextField1.setText(Name);
    jtRowData.jTextField3.setText(Price);
    jtRowData.jTextField4.setText(Category);
    jtRowData.jTextField5.setText(Method_of_Delivery);
    jtRowData.jTextField6.setText(Condition);
```

Comment: Not sure if it's me being blind here, but where is the table in your code?

Comment: @JoeC i added the code on how i get the value from my table

Answer (score 1):

It really comes down to which implementation of `TableModel` you are using.  I would suggest creating your own implementation and injecting that into your `JTable` so that you have full control over how rows are removed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do so. But, you need to access that ´JTable´?

I also suggest to move the file writing stuff into a spearate Thread, then call back with something like this:

```
// You invoke this method through a SwingWorker, ExecutorService or some other background service
void someMethodTharRunsInBackground(final JTextField jTextField1, final JTable table) {
    try(FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("BuyItem.txt", true)) { // try with resources
        writer.write(accNameTextField.getText() + "//" + jTextField1.getText() + "//" + jTextField3.getText() + "//" + jTextField4.getText() + "//" + jTextField5.getText() + "//"+ "\n");
        writer.close();
    }
     // lambda expression so you don't have to type new Runnable() { public void run() {} };
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Iteam Bought");
        table.getModel.removeRow(rowNum);
    });
}
```

Comment: i updated the code of how i get the data from my table